# (Django REST) Override Non-Editable Field in the (Views) `create` Method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my `models.py`, I create a field that is supposed to be non-editable by the user:

```py
request_status = models.CharField(
    max_length = 100,
    default = 'received', 
    editable = False
)
```

In the `views.py` file, I override the `create()` method (from the `generics.ListCreateAPIView` and `CreateModelMixin` superclasses) to activate a docker container and, if it is successfully done, I want to modify the `request_status` field to something like `container_activated` and then send back the HTTP response to the user.

So... is there a way of modifying a non-editable field? Is there a better way of setting up the `model` instead?

My best guess is that there is a way of modifying the data that gets registered in the API DB through one of the lines of the standard `create()` method (non-editable fields do not appear in the `data` property):

```py
serializer = self.get_serializer(data = request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
self.perform_create(serializer)
headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

`editable=False` doesn't mean you can't edit the field at all, it only means it won't show up in the admin or modelforms by default. In DRF, it means it will be automatically set as `read_only`; but you can override this simply defining the field manually.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    request_status = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, default='received')
    class Meta:
        ...
```

Comment: But overriding the field inside the serializer would do it every time the data is serialized, while what I wanted was for the field to change whenever a specific action is successfully performed, e.g., the creation of a docker container --- which I think should happen inside the `views.py` `create()` method. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a circumvention but it is working more or less well. I changed my field back to have `editable = True` and then I simply forced it to be a default locked (hardcoded) value. In the end, inside the `create()` of the `views.py` class, you put something like:

```py
def create(
    self, 
    request, 
    *args, 
    **kwargs
):

    # Settings of the POST request
    req_data = request.data.dict()
    req_data['request_status'] = 'not yet processed'

    # Is everything OK?
    if processing_OK == 0:
        req_data['request_status'] = 'processed'

    # Save the data
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data = req_data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
    serializer.save() # `self.perform_create(serializer)` originally
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

    # Return Response
    return Response(
        data = serializer.data,
        status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED, 
        headers = headers
    )
```

The key part was understanding that you can override what goes into the HTTP POST inside the API by altering the dictionary from `request.data.dict()`. Then you simply pass that dict (usually it's a `QueryDict` actually) inside the `self.get_serializer()` and follow the standard `create()` method.

If you configure `editable = False`, you're not able to force the changes in the way I posted here. There's probably a better way of doing this in the end.